# ViewPager + FragmentStatePagerAdapter: ViewPager stops working when screen orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, actionbarsherlock

i am using ActionBarSherlock (which is basically an extension of the Android Support Package).

What i'm trying to do is the following:

I have a `FragmentActivity` which hosts just a single `ViewPager`. This `ViewPager` has a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (because there will be many items in the future). But for now it is just loaded with 2 items for testing.

Everything is working just fine while i am in portrait orientation. But when i change so landscape orientation it switches back to the first item in the adapter (which is fine since everything is reloaded etc), but i am unable to swype to the next item. There is just nothing happening.

From debugging i can see that the `Loader` return the two items just fine. `getItem(...)` is also called with `position` 0 and 1. So basicall everything looks fine, except it isn't ;)

Btw: the same thing is happening vice versa when i start in landscape orienation and switch to portrait orientation.

Any ideas what might be wrong here?

Here is some of my code:

```
public class QuotesStatePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private List<Quote> mQuotes;

public QuotesStatePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Quote> quotes) {
    super(fm);
    mQuotes = quotes;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putSerializable("quote", mQuotes.get(position));
    QuoteFragment fragment = new QuoteFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mQuotes.size();
}
```

}

```
public QuotesFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void updateOrdering(ORDERING newOrdering) {
    mOrdering = newOrdering;
    getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).startLoading();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.quotes, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<List<Quote>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    return new QuotesLoader(getActivity(), mCategoryId);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Quote>> loader, List<Quote> data) {
    mQuotes = data;
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new QuotesStatePagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), mQuotes));
}
```

Answer (score 12):

android:configChanges="orientation" worked like a charm, but i saw that it's not recommended by android team (only last case resource)... See here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config

I found out that putting:
setRetainInstance(true); on the onCreateView of each fragment retained the instance do the trick. (please not that the onActivityCreated will be called again)

Comment: setRetainInstance(true); in onCreate is the solution! Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `android:configChanges="orientation"`to manifest inside Activity tag

Comment: In my project when I initialise the tab host I commented out the tab initialization `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
  /*if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab")); //set the tab as per the saved state
        }*/ }` That solved orienation errors for me when used in conjuction with `android:configChanges="orientation"`